# How to make sety fit any screen?

Tags: android, screen, pixel, percentage

I'm working on this app:

It gets a speed update every second. When speed is `120 km/h` I want the happy face (an `ImageView`) to be on the top, and when speed is `-120 km/h`, it should be on the bottom. `0 km/h` would be the center and so on for every speed.

[image: Speed Bar]

I calculated a relation betweeen km/h and pixels and move the face like this:

```
float pxSpeedFloat = -4.375 * speed + 115;
faceImageView.setY( -pxSpeedFloat);
```

`setY(115)` is the center of the bar, this equation works fine on `Xperia Z1.`

The problem is that it just work for this screen resolution, it doesn't fit other phones.

According to documentation, `setY` just admits value in pixels, not in % of the screen.

How do I solve it?

Comment: Can you post your relationship between speed and pixels ?

Comment: How does one go -120Km/h?

Comment: @Razgriz maybe going back to home from origin ?

Comment: @Razgriz Actually it's not a speed but a substraction, recommended speed - calculated speed. If you are faster than the recommended, it turns negative.

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz give me a moment, I'm going to calculate it again, I was trying different things and lost it.

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz Y (in pixels) = -4.375 * speed (in m/s) + 115. It works fine on Xperia Z1, setY(115) plots it on the center, and works for every speed.

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz setY(-410) is upper part of the bar for 120 km/h, setY(640) the lower for -120 km/h, so I solved this: http://imgur.com/b08qyKR (In the picture, down where I have m It should be x)

Comment: @DanielViaño i will fix your problem , can you explain me what is the maximum speed ?

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz Speed is the difference between a recommended speed and the real one. Maximum difference is 120 km/h, if you go faster it should remain in the top. In my phone the top is -410 pixels.

Comment: @DanielViaño i can explain you how i can get imageView's height and set margin programmatically but its harder way. Maybe slows application .

Answer (score 0):

try multiplying by screen density

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

faceImageView.setY(-pxSpeedFloat * metrics.density);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get the screen height:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int deviceHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
```

Then you could just work your way from that. This code would position your ImageView at the bottom of the screen:

```
imageView.setY(deviceHeight - imageView.getHeight())
```

And this code would center it vertically

```
imageView.setY((deviceHeight * 0.5) - (imageView.getHeight() * 0.5))
```

Comment: This would work great for that three positions, but not for another random one. Thanks anyway, maybe knowing device height I can work in something...

Answer (score 0):

Okey i used `FrameLayout`and measured its height. I dont konw if its efficient way but its working, maybe you can use `AsyncTask` with it, actually its `5am` in here and i have an exam. So tried this and working perfect. You can try too and come with result maybe this will fix your problem, or i will take a look at it after my exam.

1. Your global variables :

   FrameLayout frameLayout;
   int layoutheight;
   float MAX_SPEED=120;
   float MIN_SPEED=-120;
   float NEUTRAL_SPEED=0;
   float speed;
2. in `onCreate`  the point is here : [getwidth-and-getheight-of-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0)

   image=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.icon);

   frameLayout =(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
   frameLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
   //when layout ready for measuring height
   //you must wait this
   frameLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
   layoutheight= frameLayout.getHeight()/2; //height is ready
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"height : "+layoutheight,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   measureSpeed(-100);

   ```
        }
    });
   ```
3. your `measureSpeed` method :

   public void measureSpeed(int speed){
   //if speed equals 0
   if(speed==NEUTRAL_SPEED){
   FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;
   image.setLayoutParams(params);
   }
   //if speed equals or less than -120
   else if(speed<=MIN_SPEED){
   FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params.gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM;
   image.setLayoutParams(params);
   }
   //if speed equals or greater than 120
   else if(speed>=MAX_SPEED){
   FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params.gravity=Gravity.TOP;
   image.setLayoutParams(params);
   }
   //otherwise
   else{
   if(speed<NEUTRAL_SPEED){
   //less than zero
   FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
   float rate=speed/MIN_SPEED;
   float marginsize=layoutheight*rate;
   params.topMargin=(int) marginsize;
   image.setLayoutParams(params);

   ```
        }
        //greater than zero
        else if(speed>NEUTRAL_SPEED){
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
            float rate=speed/MAX_SPEED;
            float marginsize=layoutheight*rate;
            params.bottomMargin=(int) marginsize;
            image.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }
   ```

   }
4. Example xml structure: